# Tabbing into a list or combobox on a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, controls

I have an array loaded with cell addresses that are passsed into a sub that handles tab order on a sheet. I want to be able to put a control name, i.e. "MyListBox" in that array and have my function handle it. However, I cannot get it to resolve in the .activate method. If I implicitly name the control it will work but I need it to "macro expand / resolve" to the actual control name so I can say Array(x).Activate.

Here is the code I'm fumbling with to no avail. I've tried it with and without the MSFORMs declaration. I've tried concatenating the command "activesheet." & arr(x) and many other things. I'm pretty sure I'm probably missing something simple but can't seem to find it.

```
Sub TabIntercept()

Dim arr, a, x, nxt, sel
Dim cMyListBox As MSForms.ListBox

If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then Exit Sub 'Exit if (eg) a shape is selected

Set sel = Selection.Cells(1) 'if multiple cells selected use the first...

arr = GetTabOrder(ActiveSheet.Name) 'this function loads the tab order from a table

If UBound(arr) = -1 Then
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}"
    Exit Sub
End If


For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)

    If Left(arr(x), 3) = "lst" Or Left(arr(x), 3) = "cmb" Then 'Look for a control - they all start with lst/cmb

        Set cMyListBox = Sheets("Resources & Process").arr(x) 'HERE IS THE ISSUE
        arr(x).Activate
    End If

    If sel.Address() = sel.Parent.Range(arr(x)).Address() Then
        'loops back to start if at end...
        nxt = IIf(x = UBound(arr), LBound(arr), x + 1)
        sel.Parent.Range(arr(nxt)).Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code? What's `GetTabOrder` ..? Please spot more details.

Comment: The code stops line 2. After I do 'VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Forms 2.0 Library' the code stops at  'arr = ...'. Does 'arr' contain the names or the actual objects?

Comment: I'm guessing 'arr' contains the control names: 'Dim cMyListBox as Shape', ''Set cMyListBox = Sheets("Resources & Process").Shapes(arr(x))' and 'cMyListBox.Select' (probably not). 'Activate' doesn't work with a list box. What are you trying to do in the last 'If' statement?

Comment: There are no "commands", things like `Activate` are methods, that belong to objects. `arr` being a `Variant` array containing `String` elements; it's not an object, doesn't have methods - it's a data structure... not sure what `Activate` is supposed to be doing with an array.. anyway whatever is in `arr(x)` will be a string, not a member of whatever worksheet `Sheets("Resources & Process")` returns: you want to pass that control name to the sheet's `OLEObjects` collection to retrieve the control wrapper; your MSForms control is in `OLEObject.Object`.

Comment: The larger goal here is I simply want to be able to have a user tab thru the sheet in a particular order. All that GetTabOrder does is go to a table and get an array of cell address, in order, that I want to have executed. In other words, the result of that will be Array(1) = "B5", Array(2) will be "C5" and so on. I "want" to able to put "lstCoreSkills" (the name of the listbox control, in that list and have my function automatically go to that control in order when a user tabs to it. In my case, that control is the 3rd entry I want the user to arrive at so my array(3) will be "lstCoreSkills"

Comment: as I have about 12 sheets to work thru, I was trying to make a common function that I could pass parameters to as opposed to implicitly coding each one of them. to recap, I simply want a way to tab INTO this thing using a variable and not an implicit control name.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Set cMyListBox = Sheets("Resources & Process").arr(x) 'HERE IS THE ISSUE
> ```

First, declare a `Worksheet` variable for that sheet; the `Workbook.Sheets` property returns an `Object`, so all these member calls are implicitly late-bound, and you're coding blindfolded without compiler assistance.

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Resources & Process")
```

Note the `ActiveWorkbook` qualifier: if you have a specific `Workbook` object to use instead, use that. But consider always qualifying `Workbook` member calls, otherwise you're implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveWorkbook` is, and eventually that will not be the workbook you're expecting.

Now, `sheet.arr(x)` isn't going to work, as *IntelliSense* is now showing you when you type that `.` dot operator: a `Worksheet` object would have to expose an indexed property named `arr` for that to work.

What you want to do, is get the `OLEObject` *that is named* whatever the value of `arr(x)` is.

You get OLE objects from the `Worksheet.OLEObjects` property:

```
Dim oleControl As OLEObject
Set oleControl = sheet.OLEObjects(arr(x))
```

If that succeeds, you've found your MSForms control - but it's wrapped in an OLE object and we now just need to unwrap it:

```
Set cMyListBox = oleControl.Object
```

If that fails, then the MSForms control isn't compatible with the declared type of `cMyListBox`. But now you get *IntelliSense* and compile-time validation for member calls against it: if you type `cMyListBox.` and there's an `Activate` member, then the call should be valid at run-time.

Comment: Intellisense doesn't give me an .activate member so I assume it's not valid option. I just need a way to get that "object" in focus at that time, i.e. the next field the user has to address.